# polymer serve vs python -m http.server

Tags: python, html, polymer, web-component

I'm following [this document](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/install-3-0#cli).

```
npm install -g polymer-cli
git clone https://github.com/PolymerLabs/start-polymer3.git
cd start-polymer3
npm install
polymer serve
```

This works. However, if I run `python -m http.server` instead of `polymer serve`, it does not work.

What is the difference?

**polymer serve**
[image: polymer serve]

**python -m http.server**
[image: python -m http.server]

Comment: What does not work? What is it doing instead?

Comment: @abraham I added images.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your python version. Check out with Python -V then try;

```
# If Python version returned above is 3.X
python3 -m http.server
# On windows try "python" instead of "python3"
# If Python version returned above is 2.X
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Comment: I'm using anaconda and Python3. I think the version is correct. In your environment, does `python -m http.server` work?